# Cannot download video using Pytube

Tags: python, video, download, pytube

I´ve tried It many different ways, but always taht I try I get the same error, here´s an example of code I´ve tried:

```
from pytube import YouTube

def Download(link):
    youtubeObject = YouTube(link)
    youtubeObject = youtubeObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    try:
        youtubeObject.download()
    except:
        print("An error has occurred")
    print("Download is completed successfully")


link = input("Enter the YouTube video URL: ")
Download(link)
```

The error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\cosas\Codedex\Python2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "E:\cosas\Codedex\Python2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\cosas\Codedex\Python2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 33, in __init__
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\cosas\Codedex\Python2\hola\DownloadMusic.py", line 14, in <module>
    Download(link)
  File "E:\cosas\Codedex\Python2\hola\DownloadMusic.py", line 5, in Download
    youtubeObject = youtubeObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\cosas\Codedex\Python2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\cosas\Codedex\Python2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 188, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "E:\cosas\Codedex\Python2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\cosas\Codedex\Python2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 33, in __init__
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W
```

I´ve even tried different tutorials on the internet, and, still, it´s always this one error.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I haven´t found anything useful on the internet.